# How to create timed excel message pop up on top of all apps to notify user that they’ve reached their use time limit in that excel file

Tags: excel, vba, forms, popup, messagebox

There are about twenty team members who take turns opening and editing an excel file. problem is that many times users forget the file open for extended periods which stops others from accessing to make their updates. Would like to have an “ok only” message box pop up that appears above all open apps after 5 minutes of inactivity in said excel file. Also would like it to freeze other apps from being used until the pop up is cleared by clicking “OK”. Also, after clicking “OK” I would like the same message box to reappear if there is another 5 minutes of inactivity. Also would like this message to only appear if the file is open as owner. The pop up should not appear if open read only. The hope is that this pop up reminder free’s up the file for updates without delay.

**Update:
Below is the code that i ended up going with that worked for me. It starts an 8min countdown whenever there is "inactivity". If a cell is simply clicked on once and is not being edited then the countdown continues but if a cell is double clicked or actually being edited then the countdown doesn't run. Leaving a cell in edit mode is loophole that could be used to keep the file open for extended periods but I didn't find it to be abused. When editing is exited the 8min countdown starts from start. After the countdown period expires an OK message box pops up notifying that there has been 8min of inactivity and that they have 300 seconds to close the file or it will close automatically without saving but will save a copy else ware for reference. If ok is selected then the 300 seconds is cleared and the original 8min timer restarts. This is another loophole that could be used to keep the file open for extended periods but I haven't found it to be abused at all. When the file eventually does have 8min + 300sec of inactivity it  gets closed automatically and a popup appears notifying that the file has been closed without being saved but that a copy has been saved in specified location. This has worked flawlessly for about a year and has greatly if not completely fixed the delays in allowing 20 users to access the same file for daily reoccurring edits.

First part of code below is under Module 1 and Second part of code below is code for a form.

FIRST PART VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV

Option Private Module
Option Explicit

'===============================================================

Const sPROCEDURE_NAME   As String = "ShowForm_Countdown"

Private dteCloseTime    As Date

'======================================================

Public Sub Timer_Start()

```
Const sINTERVAL As String = "00:08:00"

dteCloseTime = Now + TimeValue(sINTERVAL)

On Error Resume Next

Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dteCloseTime, _
                   Procedure:=sPROCEDURE_NAME, Schedule:=True
```

End Sub

'=====================================================

Public Sub Timer_Stop()

```
On Error Resume Next

Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dteCloseTime, _
                   Procedure:=sPROCEDURE_NAME, Schedule:=False
```

End Sub

'====================================================

Private Sub ShowForm_Countdown()

```
Dim frmCountdown As F01_Countdown

Set frmCountdown = New F01_Countdown

    With frmCountdown
    
    
        If ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly = False Then
    
            .Show vbModeless
            .StartCountdown

            If .SaveWorkbook = True Then
                  Call SaveAsAndClose
            Else: Call Timer_Start
            End If
        
        End If

    End With

    Unload frmCountdown

Set frmCountdown = Nothing
```

End Sub

'=====================================================

Private Sub SaveAsAndClose()

```
Const filelocation      As String = "X:\APG\Shortlist Backups"
Const sTIMEOUT_FILE     As String = "Shortlist Timeout_Dont Delete.xlsm"

Dim sTimeOutMessageFile As String
Dim sFileNameArray()    As String
Dim sThisFileName       As String
Dim sBaseFileName       As String
Dim sNewFileName        As String
Dim sFolderPath1        As String
Dim sFolderPath2        As String
Dim sTimeStamp          As String
Dim sFullName1          As String
Dim sFullName2          As String

sTimeOutMessageFile = filelocation & "\" & sTIMEOUT_FILE

sThisFileName = ThisWorkbook.Name
sFileNameArray = Split(sThisFileName, ".")
sBaseFileName = sFileNameArray(0)

sFolderPath1 = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Documents\Shortlist Backups"
sFolderPath2 = filelocation & "\Shortlist Backups"


If Len(Dir(sFolderPath1, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir Path:=sFolderPath1
         
End If

If Len(Dir(sFolderPath2, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir Path:=sFolderPath2
         
End If

sTimeStamp = Format(Now, "hmm")

sNewFileName = sBaseFileName & "_AutoSave_" & sTimeStamp & ".xlsx"

sFullName1 = sFolderPath1 & "\" & sNewFileName
sFullName2 = sFolderPath2 & "\" & sNewFileName

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ThisWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sFullName1, FileFormat:=51
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sFullName2, FileFormat:=51

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Workbooks.Open Filename:=sTimeOutMessageFile

ThisWorkbook.Close
```

End Sub

SECOND PART VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV

Option Explicit

'==================================================

Private mbSaveWorkbook  As Boolean
Private mbCloseForm     As Boolean

'==================================================

Public Sub StartCountdown()

```
Call ShowRemainingTime
```

End Sub

'==================================================

Public Property Get SaveWorkbook() As Boolean

```
SaveWorkbook = mbSaveWorkbook
```

End Property

Private Sub lblMessage_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub lblTimeOut_Click()

End Sub

'====================================================

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

```
Dim sCaption As String

sCaption = "If file is not closed by end of countdown below the file will " & _
           "close automatically without saving and a backup of your edits " & _
           "will be saved at:" & _
            vbLf & vbLf & _
            Environ("UserProfile") & "\Documents\Shortlist Backups\"

Me.lblMessage.Caption = sCaption

Me.btnCancel.SetFocus

mbSaveWorkbook = True
mbCloseForm = False
```

End Sub

'===================================================

Private Sub btnCancel_Click()

```
mbSaveWorkbook = False
mbCloseForm = True
```

End Sub

'================================================

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

```
If CloseMode <> 1 Then

    Call btnCancel_Click
    Cancel = True

End If
```

End Sub

'==================================================

Private Sub ShowRemainingTime()

```
Const iTOTAL_SECONDS    As Integer = 300
Const iINTERVAL         As Integer = 1

Dim iSecondsElapsed     As Integer
Dim dteStartTime        As Date

Me.lblTimeOut.Caption = "in " & iTOTAL_SECONDS & " seconds"

dteStartTime = Now()
iSecondsElapsed = 0

Do

    iSecondsElapsed = iSecondsElapsed + iINTERVAL
    DoEvents

    Do
        DoEvents

    Loop While dteStartTime + (TimeValue("00:00:01") * iSecondsElapsed) >= Now() And _
               mbCloseForm = False

    Me.lblTimeOut.Caption = "in " & (iTOTAL_SECONDS - iSecondsElapsed) & " seconds"

Loop While iSecondsElapsed < iTOTAL_SECONDS And _
           mbCloseForm = False

mbCloseForm = True
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this years ago, but it was very simple and since you seems to have problems with showing the message and will post code that I tested on Excel 2013

Paste this in **ThisWorkbook**:

The timer starts in the `Workbook_Open` event, this code test for 3 seconds and shows a MsgBox

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Not ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly Then
        ' Check for owner here
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3), "module.FileTimeout"
    End If
End Sub
```

Paste this in a **module**:

The Timeout function activates the Excel application with `AppActivate` and shows a MsgBox in vbModal, so it will show on the top of all oppened apps (in theory)

```
Public Sub FileTimeout()
    AppActivate "Microsoft excel"
    MsgBox "Hey! Time has passed, close this file so others can open it!", vbInformation + vbOKOnly + vbSystemModal, "Excel timeout"
End Sub
```

Like I said I tested this code in Excel 2013 and it worked, if I minimize all the windows the MsgBox it's showed in the top, if I do something else in other app, it shows the MsgBox in the top too

If the MsgBox does not shows in the foreground for whatever reason or you just want to show a custom message with UserForm you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55079834/453348) to bring the form to the top